# MGTwitter Engine on xCode4 with iOS5 - Semantic Issues

Tags: xcode4, ios5, mgtwitterengine

My App is in the App Store and working fine.  I now want to migrate it from xCode3 to xCode4 and iOS5. I've resolved the majority of the issues, but am stuck with some warnings I'm getting (see below) relating to Matt Gemmell's excellent MGTwitterEngine.

I know I could ignore them, but I'd rather not.  There were no such warnings before. I've searched around and no one else seems to be having this trouble.  I also know I could try to change the code for each of the 11 warnings, but I suspect its some overall setting or path that's causing the issue.

Any pointers in the right direction would be warmly welcomed.

Many thanks,

Chris.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the new compiler wants you to declare protocol compliance. In your case, your twitter engine delegate class's interface declaration (in your header) should contain `< MGTwitterEngineDelegate >`. Like this:

```
@interface YourDelegateObject : NSObject < MGTwitterEngineDelegate >
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. It now appears to be an issue with Ben Gottlieb's Twitter-OAuth-iPhone library which calls MGTwitterEngine. Even the demo does the same.